# How to get picker label and value and pass to a function

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to get my picker label and value in a function because they all carry different values and I will need both the label and value content to work with. Thank you for your help

```
  onValueChangeInvoiceType(value: string){
    this.setState({
      invoiceType: value,
    });
  }



  <Picker 
    mode="dropdown" 
    style={{flex: 1}} 
    textStyle={{color: '#696969' }} 
    selectedValue={this.state.invoiceType} 
    onValueChange={this.onValueChangeInvoiceType.bind(this)}>
      <Picker.Item label="Select Option" value="" />
      <Picker.Item label="BOP" value="1" />
      <Picker.Item label="UNASSESSED BUS PROP" value="2" />
      <Picker.Item label="UNASSESSED RES PROP" value="3" />
      <Picker.Item label="FEES" value="4" />
      <Picker.Item label="FINES" value="5" />
      <Picker.Item label="BUILDING PLAN PERMIT" value="6" />
      <Picker.Item label="PERMIT CHARGES" value="7" />
      <Picker.Item label="RENT" value="8" />
      <Picker.Item label="PERMIT" value="9" />
      <Picker.Item label="BUSINESS PROPERTY RATE" value="12" />
      <Picker.Item label="RESIDENCE PROPERTY RATE" value="13" />
  </Picker>
</Item>
```

I want to know how I can pass the label content also to the onValueChangeInvoiceType function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a possible solution for you. I use a key to fetch the value/label combo from a lookup object. I use a `key` property for the lookup, since I want something I know will be unique. It can be anything you want. I'm not familiar with the particular control you're using, but this approach should work. Run the snippet below to see it function

```js
const options = [
  {value:'-1', label:'Select...', key:'-1'},
  {value:'1', label:'BOP', key:'A'},
  {value:'2', label:'UNASSESSED BUS PROP', key:'B'},
  {value:'3', label:'UNASSESSED RES PROP', key:'C'},
  {value:'4', label:'FEES', key:'D'},
  {value:'5', label:'FINES', key:'E'},
];


  
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      value: '',
      label: ''
    };
  }

  onChange = (e) => {
    const opt = options.find(op => op.key === e.target.value);
    if(opt){
      this.setState({
        value: opt.value,
        label: opt.label
      })
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <select onChange={this.onChange}>
          {options.map(({key,label}) => (
            <option key={key} label={label} value={key} />
          ))}
        </select>
        <p>Value: {this.state.value}</p>
        <p>Label: {this.state.label}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you Ted I really appreciate you help with try this and get back to you.